# Json encoding, customizing dumps method

Tags: python, json

I have the following dictionary:

```
data = {
    'name': 'david',
    'avatar': '\xed\xb3\x1cW\x7f\x87\x1c\xb9*Pw\x9a#W\x05\xeaNs\xe4\xaa@\xddi\x8e\\\x15\xa8;\xcd\x91\xab\x02u\xa79rU\xa0\xee4\xf7K\xb9\x05{t\x02\xc6I\xb6\xaa\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82...'
}
```

When I try doing:

```
import json
json.dumps(data)
```

I get a `UnicodeDecodeError`, probably because it's trying to interpret the `avatar` data.

How would I 'skip' a value when doing json-encoding, so the value of the key just uses its string and doesn't try and encode it?

Comment: I believe if you add a 'u' in from of the string ie `u'1w\x...'`

Comment: JSON supports strings of Unicode text only; you’d store a sequence of bytes as an array of integers.

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE thanks for the recommendation. How would I do this in practice?

Comment: In Python 3, it’s as easy as `'avatar': list(b'1w\xed…')`. In Python 2, I have no idea. `map(ord, '…')`?

Comment: @user2097159 for that I also get the same UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: If you need to send binary data over JSON (which is what you appear to be doing), then you'll need to encode the binary data into something compatible with JSON. I'd suggest you take a look at base64 encoding, which is probably fine for your purposes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html Note that whatever is receiving the data at the other end will then need to decode this back to the binary data.